# Cloud Run Billing Report GCP not shown when filtering by label

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, cost-management, google-cloud-billing

I've added labels to the projects in Google Cloud Run GCP, so that I can view the **cost filtered by env label to the billing report** ( *key: env and value: prod* ). Regardless of applying any label to Cloud Run, Cost Table does not show the service, even if I do not have any other Cloud Run services without the env label.

I tried redeploying the services a month ago, but nothing changed.

Any idea how to resolve?

Below images show attached labels and the problem inside the Cost Table.

[image: Here Labels attached to Cloud Run]

[image: Here Cost Table without filtering by label]

[image: Here Cost Table when filtering by label]

Comment: Try changing **Group by** to **Label keys**

Comment: @JohnHanley unfortunately as far I can see the costs when grouping by label keys does not count Google Cloud Run labelled services

Comment: What happens when you change **Group by**? Did you also enable exporting billing data to BigQuery?

Comment: @JohnHanley It happens that the total count by Label does not count Google Cloud Run consumptions. Yes I have billing data to BigQuery

Comment: Your responses are too terse, I have no idea what is happening on your screen.

Comment: @JohnHanley the problem is that neither in BigQuery GCP cost data I cannot see Cloud Run. Have you got labeled Cloud Run figuring on your Cloud Platform Cost Table?

Comment: Hi, have you defined the labels through .yaml file?

Comment: @ZeenathSN nope I defined them via terraform

Comment: I think you will have to check if you have made some mistake in defining the labels via terraform, or I suggest you raise a [Google Cloud support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases), it will be helpful in knowing the root cause.

Comment: @pualien did you ever resolve this issue? I am observing similiar behavior. I have Cloud Run services that I have been deploying over a period of ~months with labels. I am able to confirm the labels are being applied to the Cloud Run services. I see a subset (not all!) of the labels listed in Cloud Billing reports. I am unable to "Group By" the label keys that are being caught by billing but the report does not enumerate the label's values. Curiously, I can filter the reports by one of the labels and it finds a single value (there should be more). This appears to be buggy. Did you report it?

Comment: Filed an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241812812

Comment: @DazWilkin I haven't resolved yet. I agree that seems buggy, and thanks for filed the issue

Comment: I think *my* issue is that I've been unable to generate enough Cloud Run spend for the labels to appear. Are you incurring cost attributable to the labels?

Comment: @pualien Did you do anything to show that Label filter on the Billing page? In my case, smh, the Label section is not even there. I have set a label on one of my Cloud Run services. However, the Label filter is still not there even after days of waiting.

Comment: @pualien I just found that in this billing tutorial video (https://youtu.be/jRb8piwa2GI?t=97), the Label filter seems not enabled by default. In the video, the menu has no Label filter. Therefore, might I know how you enabled this Label filter in your case?

Comment: @DazWilkin yes even if I have costs within Google Cloud Run nothing appears when also grouping on labels

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji as you see in the images I can filter on labels (also grouping on them), but no costs linked Google Cloud Run appears within the labels

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/labels#yaml), the label must be applied to `spec.template.metadata.label`.

> `metadata.labels` sets labels on the service object, while `spec.template.metadata.label` sets labels on the created revision. **Only labels set on the revision are passed to logs and billing.**

Emphasis mine. This key piece of information is only provided under the YAML implementation. The terraform tab simply states:

> Add the following to a `google_cloud_run_service` resource in your Terraform configuration, under the `template` attribute

```
metadata {
  # Labels
  # https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/labels
  labels = {
    foo : "bar"
    baz : "quux"
  }
}
```

Looking at the issue you raised, it looks like you have set the label on the service object rather than the revision. I made the same mistake at first, too!

Comment: ok, so beside the labels that I have right now in terraform via google_cloud_run_service.metadata.labels where I have to put the other ones?

Comment: google_cloud_run_service.spec.template.metadata.labels